# Accessing inherited properties through a static class

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, inheritance, static

Currently, I am accessing the property by creating a static method like the one below.

```
public static class CartCollection : List<Cart>
{
    public static void Add(Cart Cart)
    {
        Add(Cart);
    }
}
```

All I am trying to achieve is to have access to all the properties of List<>.

Outside of the class, I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
Cart cart = new Cart();
cart.SomeProperty = 0;
CartCollection.Add(cart);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't your `Add` an endless recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't inherit from `List<>`, embed one:

```
public static class CartCollection
{
    private static List<Cart> _list = new List<Cart>();

    public static void Add(Cart Cart)
    {
        _list.Add(Cart);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the variable name in the declaration of `_list`.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) Don't inherit `List<T>`.  Implement `IList<T>`.

2) Use a singleton:

```
public class CartCollection : IList<Cart>
{
    public static readonly CartCollection Instance = new CartCollection();

    private CartCollection() { }

    // Implement IList<T> here
}
```

Also, as you are using this in an ASP.NET app, you should know that static members are shared by **all** requests.  Using this kind of code without `lock`ing appropriately may lead to crashes.  And even if you use `lock`, you will share data between your users, which you may not want...

Answer (score 0):

Why subclass List at all? If you're not adding additional functionality, why not just use `List<Cart>`?

```
public static class CartCollection
{
    public static readonly List<Cart> Instance = new List<Cart>();
}

Cart cart = new Cart();
cart.SomeProperty = 0;
CartCollection.Instance.Add(cart);
```

Comment: your code is good enough, but I suppose, using `Design Patterns` is always considered a `good programming practice`.